# Need an explanation of this scripting command

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, administrative

What does the command `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin` accomplish?

I would like to understand this more than I already do; please assist!

Comment: and what do you already understand? without that, it is hard to answer.

Comment: well i think that is It modifies the system path variable.. which causes system utilities to be able to locate commands used in shell scripting, and to test for their syntax?

Comment: or does it just copy the environment PATH variable to the local variable space?

Comment: To add from others' answers, it doesn't modify the PATH variable permanently. It will only affect the current shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PATH` is an environment variable that specifies directories to be searched (in order from left-to-right) to find executables. When you invoke something like `gzip`, the `$PATH` environment variable is split on `:` and each of those paths is searched to see if it contains `gzip`.

It is common to prepend directories to this variable, so that they are searched before the existing (default) locations. This is generally done when you want to add a non-standard directory to the PATH, so that you can install applications to subdirectories.

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

This *appends* `~/bin` (i.e. "$HOME/bin") to the PATH, so that you can execute scripts/binaries from the "bin" folder in your home directory.

You can determine which command will be executed from your PATH by using the `which` command. For example:

```
-bash$ which gzip
/usr/bin/gzip
```

You can also drop the `export` keyword, but in doing this, the changed PATH variable will not be visible to scripts invoked from your bash shell.

Take a look at the output of `echo $PATH` or `env | grep PATH` to see what that variable looks like.

Answer (score 1):

It modifies the current setting of the `PATH` environment variable and (re)exports it.

The change is to add `~/bin` to the `PATH` so it will, as a last resort, look in the `bin` directory under your home directory (specified by `$HOME`, which is normally but not necessarily the same as your login directory as specified in the password database and identified by `~username`) for a command.  This means that there's an extra place to search for commands.

Personally, I put my `bin` directory at the front of my `PATH`; my commands override other people's commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

will append `~/bin` to your current `$PATH` in your current shell.

If you put it in one of your shell's init files, such as `~/.bashrc` for `bash`, you could add `~/bin` to your `$PATH` permanently.